# Semantic UI - How to get data of active Input Element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html, semantic-ui

how can I get the value of the input field to the urlData Object?

```
<input id="username">
```

And the JS is:

```
$('#username').api({
   action: 'check username',
    urlData: {username: $(this).val()},
    onSuccess: function(response){
        console.log(response)
    },
    onError: function(error){
        console.log(error)
    }
});`
```

With normal `JQuery` i can get it with an `$(this).val();`.  But in this case it´s empty. How does it work with Semantic UI ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this

```
 $( "#username" ).keyup(function() {
    var value=$(this).val();
    $('#username').api({
       action: 'check username',
        urlData: {username: value},
        onSuccess: function(response){
            console.log(response)
        },
        onError: function(error){
            console.log(error)
        }
    });
 });
```

Comment: That´s not correctly working.. when I typein '123456' i have only the value of '12345'. The last on is missing. It´s not sending the correct input value.

Comment: ok fine in that case use like this $('#username').bind("change keyup input",function() { });

Answer (score 1):

for anyone who can't figure out why the request does not run immediately (typed 'abc' then the request just 'ab'), here's the solution!

---

(I'm going to using example above)
You can just add

> on:'now'

explicitly make semanticjs api to do request 'now', as the keyup(or any events) handle the rest.

```
$( "#username" ).keyup(function() {
var value=$(this).val();
$('#username').api({
   action: 'check username',
   on:'now',
    urlData: {username: value},
    onSuccess: function(response){
        console.log(response)
    },
    onError: function(error){
        console.log(error)
    }
});
});
```

I decide to answer this pretty old question, might be someone needs it!

Comment: This one works so far, but: If I have several elements like `id='element_1'`, `id='element_2'` and using a wildcard selector like `'[id^=element_]'`, it fires for every single element that machtes the wildcard. Let's discuss it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49508257/semantic-ui-adding-api-using-wildcard-selector-and-get-access-to-the-specific