# Semantic-UI: adding .api using wildcard selector and get access to the specific element

Tags: api, jquery-selectors, wildcard, semantic-ui

As seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44706714/3545267) the selectors id `#username` is binded twice and nested. In the first binding, the value can be set with `$(this).val();` and the be used in the second, nested binding for the Semantic-UI API.

But what if I have several elements like `element_1`, `element_2` etc?

Right now, I'm using this code, but the event is fired for each element that matches the wildcard `[id^=unbind_]`and not only (like it should be) for the clicked element:

```
$(document).on('click','[id^=unbind_]', function(){
    var permission=$(this).attr('data-value');
    var id=$(this).attr('id');
    var role_id=$(this).attr('data-roleid');
    //console.log('Permission:' + id);
    $('[id^=unbind_]')
        .api({
            action: 'unbind permissions',
            on: 'now',
            method: 'DELETE',
            data: { 'permission': permission},
            onSuccess: function(data) {
                console.log('SUCCESS: ' + id);
                remove_element(id);
                decr('#role_cnt_' + role_id);
            }
        });
});
```